# Pullback Solid Angle, Stereographic projection

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have an issue with a differential geometry task. Given is the solid angle form:

$$\omega = \frac{\epsilon_{ijk} x^i dx^j \wedge dx^k}{2 [ (x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2 +(x^3)^2]^{3/2}}$$

The aim of the task is to integrate this form over the unity sphere $S^2$. Now let $h_+^{-1}$ be the inverse stereographic projection map (without north):
$ h_+^{-1}: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow S^2 \setminus N$, $h_+^{-1}=\left(\frac{2y^1}{||y||^2+1} , \frac{2y^2}{||y||^2+1}, \frac{||y||^2-1}{||y||^2+1} \right)$.

Task a) is to compute the pullback $h_+^{-1}* (\omega)$ and task b) is to integrate the form over the sphere.

Now: I know how to compute a pullback and I know that I can integrate the pulled-back form over the changed domain. But the calculation for the pullback seems to be much too long. I do not think that I'm doing it correctly by straight-forwardly calculating the pullback. I didn't finish the calculation yet, but the result seems to be in a very ugly form, which I don't know to integrate either. Can someone please help me and give me a hint how this should be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize in spherical coordinates!

Comment: Hm, in task c) (which I have already done) I have to use spherical coordinates to calculate the integral. If I use them now too, the tasks would be identical, wouldn't they? Or do I misunderstand something there?

Comment: No, apparently you did not. This is a pretty horrendous calculation, presumably intended to make you understand the importance of choosing a "good" parametrization. :) It's somewhat easier to compute the pullback of the usual *metric* on $S^2$ (this is often called the spherical metric on $\Bbb C$) and then the area form is immediate from that.

Comment: Right: I just meant that computing the pullback of the metric $\sum dx^j\otimes dx^j$ by the map $h_+^{-1}$ is easier than pulling back the area $2$-form. Did you instructor perhaps intend for you to use some computer algebra system?

Comment: Ok, I am confused now. In c) I used spherical coordinates and with a map:
Q: $$[0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow S^2$$
$$(\theta,\phi) \rightarrow (\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta)$$
I calculated the integral with the pullback $$ \int Q*(\omega)$$ which was quite easy. I'm not sure how to use the spherical coordinates while using the spherical projection now. Do I have to use a second pullback?

Comment: No, no, I didn't know about part (c) when you posted your question and so my advice was inappropriate. But I don't quite know what your instructor had in mind with part (a); can you use Mathematica or something similar?

Comment: Ah, ok sorry for the confusion. Well I calculated some parts of the pullback already with Wolfram Alpha but I am not quite sure if my result is correct. I was hoping there is some smart way to calculate the pullback and integrate it, but it seems that doing the whole calculation is really the only way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but the answer actually comes out quite nicely when you've done it correctly.

Comment: Alright, then i will do it this way. The fact that i already know, that the result is $4\pi$ makes this a little bit easier. Thanks for your help.